# Oldstyle figure 1 in EB Garamond

Tags: ebgaramond

Using `ebgaramond` package, is there any way to get an oldstyle figure 1 that looks like a shorter 1 rather than a shorter I?

Comment: Really oldstyle `1`s do look like a small caps `I`.

Comment: I know, but `garamondx` uses such a modified oldstyle 1.

Comment: @totera `garamondx` oldstyle 1 is ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ebgaramond` package provides no means for using the glyph you want, but if you use `xetex` or `luatex`, you don’t need the package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[UprightFeatures={CharacterVariant=11}]
\begin{document}
12345
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

This variant is available only in the roman, not the italic.

Note that this solution works for the EB Garamond from [Georg Duffner](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/); TeX Live contains only the modified fonts from [Octavio Pardo](https://github.com/octaviopardo/).  The latter require that you specify `Numbers=OldStyle` and, although they contain the glyph you want (`one.01`), they provide no feature for using it.  With LuaLaTeX, you can create a feature on the fly for this modified EB Garamond:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature{
    name = "wxyz",
    type = "alternate",
    data = {
      ["one.osf"] = "one.01",
      ["one.tosf"] = "one.tosf01",
    },
  }
}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[
  Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},
  RawFeature=+wxyz]
\begin{document}
12345

\addfontfeature{Numbers=Tabular}12345
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I change lua code to obtain this in EB Garamond 12 ?

Comment: @ReRunner I assume you’re referring to Georg Duffner’s fonts, in which case the first part of my answer works.

Comment: @Thérèse, Is there a way to get bold and/or bold-italic figure of it under XeLaTeX?