# Font features of EBGaramond don't work correctly

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, ebgaramond

```
%% Fontspec provides an interface to system fonts and Opentype features
\usepackage{fontspec}

 %% Load default features. An asterisk means they are supposed to be
 %% enabled by default, but engines may behave differently.
 \defaultfontfeatures{%
  RawFeature={%
    %+calt   % *Contextual alternates
    %,+clig  % *contextual ligatures
    %,+ccmp  % *composition & decomposition
    %,+tlig  % 'tex-ligatures': `` '' -- --- !` ?` << >>
    %,+cv06  % narrow guillemets
    ,+dlig
    }%
  }

 %% Finally set the main font
 \setmainfont{EB Garamond}


%% Use polyglossia to handle different languages.
\usepackage[%
  babelshorthands % needed to access "| as a ZWNJ symbol
  ]{polyglossia}
 \setdefaultlanguage{english}
 \setotherlanguages{%
  french,czech,polish,latin,italian,catalan,german,romanian,%
  portuges,swedish,finnish,dutch,russian,serbian,ukrainian,%
  bulgarian,slovenian,vietnamese,greek%
  }

%% Multicol for the two-column samples
\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}

\section{Samples}
%% Samples that show the font used in different languages.
\begin{multicols}{2}

%% English
\paragraph*{Claude Garamond} (ca. 1480 – 1561) was a Parisian publisher. He was one of the leading type designers  of his time, and is credited with the introduction of the apostrophe, the accent and the cedilla to the French language. Several contemporary typefaces, including those currently known as Garamond, Granjon, and Sabon, reflect his influence. Garamond was an apprentice of Simon de Colines; later, he was an assistant to Geoffroy Tory, whose interests in humanist typography and the ancient Greek capital letterforms, or majuscules, may have informed Garamond’s later work.

\textit{Garamond came to prominence in 1541, when three of his Greek typefaces (e.g. the Grecs du roi (1541)) were requested for a royally-ordered book series by Robert Estienne. Garamond based these types on the handwriting of Angelo Vergecio, the King’s Librarian at Fontainebleau, as well as that of his ten-year-old pupil, Henri Estienne. According to Arthur Tilley, the resulting books are “among the most finished specimens of typography that exist.” Shortly thereafter, Garamond created the Roman types for which […]}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

This is extracted from the specimen file of the EBGaramond font https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond/tree/master/specimen
In the pdf they describe the font features and how to selectively enable the ligatures.  But none of the commands put in `RawFeature` seem to work, except the command `+dlig`, which seems to enable all possible ligatures, even the ancient ones.  How to selectively enable the ligatures, and why don't the font features work? (This has been tested under both xelatex and lualatex.  I've tested the font features with the `\setff` command also in OpTeX, and even there the behaviour is the same.)

Comment: there are two version of EBGaramond around, see e.g. here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/531734/2388. Which one do you have?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  The one that comes with TeXLive, I have never manually installed it

Comment: The version in TeX Live lacks these and several other features of the version with which that specimen goes.