# XCharter with old style figures prints 1 like a shortened I instead of 1 like a shortened 1

Tags: fonts, oldstylenums, xcharter

I'm trying to create a template in `pdfLaTeX` using the excellent XCharter package. According to the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/xcharter/doc/xcharter-doc.pdf), the `osf` package option should load old-style figures, and the numeral 1 should be displayed like a shortened 1, while the `osfI` option should load old-style figures with the numeral 1 like a shortened `I`.

However, I am getting the shortened `I` version even with the `osf` option. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[osf]{XCharter}
\begin{document}

This is the numeral 1.

\end{document}
```

I've also made [the MWE on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/qrmqbpbnmphx). As you can clearly see, what is displayed is the shortened `I` numeral 1. What's going on?

I thought perhaps this might have to do with the Overleaf version of packages, but the logs clearly show that the latest version of *XCharter* is being used. Compiling locally on my machine shows the same.

[image]

Comment: This is by design. Some typefaces offer alternates: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/531733

Comment: Hmm perhaps -- but the documentation clearly specifies that `osf` prints the shortened 1, and that `osfI` prints the shortened `I`. This seems to be a bug.

Comment: The `README` file in the documentation folder gives the author’s email address for bug reports.

Comment: looks like a bug, report it to the author.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's weird indeed. When I compile your MWE using LuaLatex I get the desired output without a hitch, but using PDFLatex gives the same output as you provided, no matter how I use the `oldstyle` option.

Putting `\osfstyle` in front of the `1` however gives the correct output even in PDFLatex.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[osf]{XCharter}

\begin{document}
    
    This is the numeral 1.
    
    This is the numeral \osfstyle 1.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The traditional form of the lowercase `1`, the one that resembles a small cap `i`, is the default lowercase `1` in the `.otf` file; the other lowercase `1`, which the O.P. prefers, is in the `cv01` feature. There’s probably a way to make `pdflatex` use it by redefining something in `XCharter.sty`.

Comment: Ah of course, its `pdflatex`'s fault! Yeah this seems to be a bug when using `pdflatex`. @Thérèse do you think there's a way to redefine this only for my document? Like assigning old style 1 to be the one I want while using `pdflatex`.
I've already convinced myself that the right answer is to always use `xelatex` 

Comment: As I started to migrate from PDFLatex to LuaLatex I came across some issues with ‘older’ fonts. I used the `Charter` set of `mathdesign` to denote the Greek upright symbols in my chemistry entries. That option is based on `Charter BT`. I tried `XCharter` as an alternative. Works fine under LuaLatex, but under PDFLatex I had the feeling it was off a bit.

Comment: @Venkat Using `lualatex` is better since, unlike `xelatex`, it’s very actively maintained. I haven’t used `pdflatex` in years, so I’m not the person to suggest fixes to  the `.sty` file.

Comment: @Thérèse wasn’t `XCharter` specifically developed to be used with `fontspec` / `Unicode` coding instead of the traditional `fontenc` / `utf8` coding? Thought I came across a remark to that effect somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I'm absolute beginner, but after some digging into the code I found the following:

- The correct `1` can be obtained with `pdfLatex` by using the option `proportional` (default is `tabular`)

  ```
  \usepackage[osf,proportional]{XCharter}
  ```
- To obtain the correct `1` while still using the default `tabular` option, I modified the encoding file `AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts\enc\dvips\xcharter\xch1_dp2hrq.enc` by changing

  ```
  %30
    /zero.tosf /one.tosf /two.tosf /three.tosf /four.tosf /five.tosf /six.tosf /seven.tosf
    /eight.tosf /nine.tosf /colon /semicolon /less /equal /greater /question
  ```

  into

  ```
  %30
    /zero.tosf /one.Alt.tosf /two.tosf /three.tosf /four.tosf /five.tosf /six.tosf /seven.tosf
    /eight.tosf /nine.tosf /colon /semicolon /less /equal /greater /question
  ```

  and thus changing the style of the `1`.

  Why this file? Well, I looked it in `AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts\map\dvips\xcharter\XCharter.map` to see which file corresponds to `XCharter1-Roman-tosf-t1`.

I don't have any experience with fonts or Tex code, but for me this worked. Hope it helps!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.